# Make div track to page scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Alright, I have a custom div (its a vertical line) that I need to track to page scroll. The page itself is `overflow: hidden;` and fixed, so with no listening to scroll events, this div isn't going anywhere.

I need some kind of offset based on scroll and an initial value so that while the page stays static, this div will move like a scroll bar. The div:

```
.scrollBar {
    width: 2px;
    height: 55px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

How can I do this?

My main frame css:

```
position: fixed;
        display: none;
        z-index: 10000;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: grid;
        align-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        max-width: none;
```

Comment: You're looking for position sticky probably if not i'm not sure what you're trying do

Comment: I'm guessing you really want `overflow-y:scroll;` or `overflow-y:auto;` on your `.scrollBar`.

Comment: @StackSlave that didnt work - I think its because no scrolling is actually happening? Due to the main div being fixed? See the edit

Comment: Where's your HTML? Why not make a snippet?

Answer (score 0):

try to change scrollBar width more than 15px and overflow-y:scroll;